# How do you use a frozen dataclass in a dictionary and export it to YAML?

Tags: python, yaml, python-dataclasses

I want to dump to YAML a dictionary that is using a frozen dataclass as key, and then read it back, like in this minimum example:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

import yaml

@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Person:
    name: str


p = Person("Jane")

d = { p: "Hi!"}

with open("data_t.yaml", "w") as f:
    yaml.dump(d, f)

with open("data_t.yaml", "r") as f:
    d2 = yaml.load(f, Loader=yaml.Loader)

print(d2)
```

However, I get this error on the `load` line:

```
File "/OMITTED/python3.9/site-packages/yaml/constructor.py", line 144, in construct_mapping
mapping[key] = value
File "<string>", line 3, in __hash__
AttributeError: 'Person' object has no attribute 'name'
```

The generated YAML file is this:

```
? !!python/object:__main__.Person
  name: Jane
: Hi!
```

I think that the problem is related to the fact the dataclass is frozen and that generates some problem when constructing it. Is that really the problem? Anyway, is there a way around it, without giving up frozen dataclasses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define custom functions for dumping and loading. I cannot test this with `@dataclass` since my Python version is too old but I think this should work:

```py
import yaml

@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Person:
    yaml_tag = "!person"

    name: str

    @staticmethod
    def to_yaml(dumper, data):
        node = dumper.represent_mapping(Person.yaml_tag,
            {"name": data.name})
        node.flow_style = True
        return node

    @staticmethod
    def from_yaml(loader, node):
        node = loader.construct_mapping(node)
        return Person(node["name"])

yaml.SafeDumper.add_representer(Person, Person.to_yaml)
yaml.SafeLoader.add_constructor(Person.yaml_tag, Person.from_yaml)

d = { Person("Jane"): "Hi!" }

txt = yaml.dump(d, stream=None, Dumper=yaml.SafeDumper)
print(txt)
loaded = yaml.load(txt, yaml.SafeLoader)
print(loaded)
```

Be sure to use `SafeDumper` / `SafeLoader` because `yaml.Loader` can execute arbitrary class constructors which is a security risk.

I used the local tag `!person` to make the YAML file nicer and formatted the Person node to have flow style. You can of course change this to your liking.

**Edit:**

Here's how to write a decorator that does this to your class:

```py
class yamlEnabled(object):
    def __init__(self, tag):
        self.tag = tag

    def __call__(self, cls):
        def to_yaml(dumper, data):
            return dumper.represent_mapping(self.tag, vars(data))
        yaml.SafeDumper.add_representer(cls, to_yaml)
        def from_yaml(loader, node):
            data = loader.construct_mapping(node)
            return cls(**data)
        yaml.SafeLoader.add_constructor(self.tag, from_yaml)
        return cls
```

Use it like

```
@yamlEnabled("!person")
@dataclass(frozen=True)
class Person:
    name: str
```

(Not tested with an actual `@dataclass` because my Python version is too old)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The code works. However, it's a lot of code for just a simple class with one str field, and I have many classes with more complex types.

In addition, if I just change the line where the dictionary is defined to d = { (Person("Jane"), Person("John")): "Hi!" }, it stops working.

On the other hand, I don't care about the security implications because I'm only consuming objects that I create, so if it was easier with yaml.Loader, I would use it. Right now, the alternative I see is using pickle, which is even less secure.

Comment: This code shows you how it works generally, you can remodel it into function so that you can do `setup_yaml(Person)` on any number of types; `from_yaml` and `to_yaml` can be defined more generally as lambdas in there. You can even write a decorator so that you can do `@yamlEnabled @dataclass`. As for the tuple thing, that is solvable but is a different question so please ask a new question for that.

Comment: Added decorator definition to answer.